# Why does iam.listUsers only retrieve 100 users when using the AWS SDK for Javascript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

When I try to retrieve all the IAM users in my AWS account through Javascript, only 100 users are returned even though I have 370 users in my account.

```
await iam.listUsers().promise();
```

Answer (score 2):

From [ListUsers - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html):

> **MaxItems**
>
> Use this only when paginating results to indicate the maximum number of items you want in the response. If additional items exist beyond the maximum you specify, the `IsTruncated` response element is `true`.
>
> If you do not include this parameter, **the number of items defaults to 100**. Note that IAM might return fewer results, even when there are more results available. In that case, the `IsTruncated` response element returns true, and Marker contains a value to include in the subsequent call that tells the service where to continue from.
>
> **Type:** Integer
>
> **Valid Range:** Minimum value of 1. Maximum value of 1000.